# Getting Template Column in ASP.NET Gridview to rebind

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I've got a very simple ASP.NET WebForms app with a GridView that binds to a SqlDataSource.  In that gridview, i've used the default "Edit" handling of the gridview which is working as expected to updated the data.

However, I have a Template field that gets data with a method called (as below) and that template column does not update when I press the automatically generated updated button.  When I refresh the page, it does update.  I've experimented with databind in the row_updated/updating events but with no success.

```
Gridview...
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="New $" >
 <ItemTemplate>
    <%#  GetSampleCalc((int) Eval("id")) %>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Have you tried EditItemTemplate? Use EditItemTemplate and place your textbox or whatever controls inside this template. And then use code to find this control on Item_Updating event. And save your data there.

Comment: Hmm. It's the ItemTemplate that I need to update though.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question.